# struggling with setting a range based on a variable

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

The end user will choose from a listbox, which outputs the row of their choice into B,2 The value of which will indicate the starting row. They'll also need a way to input the number of rows, but I am stuck on this first part. Any help will be greatly appreciated

I tried using the Activecell.Offset() which worked perfectly, but quickly realized it wouldn't due to the following. The schedule sheet is where they will start, but there are 6 pages that will need different ranges pasted onto them, so after the first page, the active cell will be gone.
I am hoping to do something like:
choose the first build of the day which indicates the starting row.. say 55...
then the planned # of builds for the day... let's say 5.
I would need row 57:61 to paste onto sheet 2/
56:60 on another/
55:59 on a different... so on and on...
this is where I am currently.
It's coming back with "424 object required".

```
Sub Denest()
'
' Denest Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Denest").Select
    Rows("3:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
    Sheets("Incoming").Select
    Dim var As Variant
    var = Range("B1").Value
    
    Dim nrange As Range
    Set nrange = Range(var, var.Offset(2, 0).Rows("1:5")).EntireRow.Select  <------error here
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Denest").Activate
    Sheets("Denest").Rows("3:3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

I'm clearly missing something here...

Comment: I need to repetitively copy, paste separate, re-format rows from one sheet into 6 other sheets.
let's say we have the number 6 in cell B2 and the number 5 in C2
Is it possible to write a macro to copy 5 rows starting at row 8   aka row(6+2) aka row 10 into sheet2
my brain interperets
copy the range Row("6+2":"12") to sheet2
               Row("6+3":"13") to sheet3
               Row("6+4":"14") to sheet4
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

- var is in your code a number, but you need an object.
- If you want the next five rows after the second row from cell B1

```
    Sheets("Denest").Select
    Rows("3:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
    Sheets("Incoming").Select
    Dim var As Variant
    Set var = Range("B1")          'edited
    
    Dim nrange As Range
    Set nrange = var.Offset(2,0).Rows("1:5").EntireRow.Select         'edited
    'Set nrange = Range(var, var.Offset(2, 0).Rows("1:5")).EntireRow.Select  <------error here
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Denest").Activate
    Sheets("Denest").Rows("3:3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

The above code is only the correction of the posted one.

EDIT: This is the code which does the following

- Place in **shnames** Array the target sheets name
- Place in **orig** the sheet name to copy
- In orig sheet B2 the first row to copy
- In orig sheet C2 the count of rows

The result:

The C2 count of rows from B2 row of orig sheet are copied into the shnames Array sheets with an incrementing start of rows from B2 + 2.

```
Sub multicopy()
 shnames = Array("YY1", "xx1", "zz1")
 Dim orig As Worksheet
 Set orig = Worksheets("to copy")         'edited
 Dim nrange As Range
 
 For i = 0 To UBound(shnames)
   With Sheets(shnames(i))
      .Rows("3:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
      orig.Rows(orig.Range("B2")).Rows("1:" & orig.Range("C2")).Copy
      .Rows(orig.Range("B2") + 2 + i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
   End With
 Next i
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: This just pastes the number 12 in the enire row 3

Comment: @jr stroik Pls. check the new version according to your comment in the question.

Comment: You're a genius! Thanks a million times!  The array works perfectly. A few changes needed to be made to the spreadsheet so I was easily able to move the the orig.range to wherever it was convenient. Plus I can add sheets and additional ranges!